# How to discard useless zero digits from decimals?

Tags: python

I'm new in Python and I have a problem about the decimal library.

Some questions require that all zeros after the decimal point located behind the last non-zero digit must be discarded.[UVA11821](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/118/p11821.pdf)

Such as `0.1230000` is an illegal answer .It should be converted into `0.123`.

I plan to do this question in python and decimal.However, I am not able to do the convert job.
And here is my code.

```
from decimal import *
a=eval(input())
con=getcontext()
con.prec=100
for i in range(0,a):
        summ=Decimal('0')
        while 1:
                num=Decimal(input())
                if num==0:
                        break;
                summ=summ+num
        print(summ)
```

Comment: `eval(input())` CAUTION CAUTION CAUTION... https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: @Ralf: Please don't make changes like that to a question's code. You can do it in answer if you post one, of course.

Comment: `a=int(input())` does the job and is safe.

Comment: @martineau may I know why? I though it improved readability without changing the outcome when running the code.

Comment: @Ralf: Because there's too much of a potential to change the original question and introduce new, but different, errors.

Comment: As for me, it's a competitive programming question... Perhaps using dangerous code in a task isn't real dangerous....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try [normalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize)?

> Normalize the number by stripping the rightmost trailing zeros and converting any result equal to Decimal('0') to Decimal('0e0').

It should work in your case.

```
import decimal
print(decimal.Decimal('0.1230000').normalize())
0.123
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to convert numbers like `1.29E+3` into `1290` since the latter is the output format in the problem.

Comment: print('%.f' % 1.29E+3)
1290

Answer (score -1):

A very basic posibility is to work on the `str` output.

```
s = '0.1230000'
if '.' in s:
    while len(s) > 0 and s[-1] == '0':
        s = s[:-1]
```

Its not very elegant, but it does the job. But this is more work if you need to convert it back to a `Decimal` instance afterwards.

EDIT: added basic check to only remove zeros after the decimal point.

Comment: `if '.' in s: s = s.rstrip("0")` would be more elegant