# How to print a decimal number up to n decimal values neglecting 0's if any at the end?

Tags: python, printing, number-formatting

I am trying to print the values of two numbers up to 4 decimal places excluding 0's if any at the end.

```py
a= 0.125
b= 0.256325

print("%.4f" %round(a,4))
print("%.4f" %round(b,4))
```

This gives me 0.1250 and 0.2563 but I want only 0.125 for a and 0.2563 for b

I expect:

if a is 0.125, 0.1250 or 0.125000, I should get only 0.125 as output and for all the other cases I can get 4 non zero values after "."

Comment: `str(round(a, 4))` results in '0.125' with Python 3.7.3 (and '0.2563' for `str(round(b, 4))`).

Comment: Is it possible to get the desired result in C language.

Answer (score 0):

try `normalize` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52665935/how-to-discard-useless-zero-digits-from-decimals)

```
import decimal 
print(decimal.Decimal('0.1230000').normalize())
0.123
```

for your example

```
a= 0.125
b= 0.256325

print (decimal.Decimal(str.format('%.4f' %a)).normalize())
print (decimal.Decimal(str.format('%.4f' %b)).normalize())

0.125
0.2563
```